# Trying to add search bar admin panel menu bar searching woocommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to add a product search bar to Wordpress admin bar backend that will do Woocommerce product search. It will be located in the backend Admin Menu bar a top so that no matter where you are in back end it will allow to search woo's products. I am close but faulting at small stumbling block. When trying to use the search it is defaulting to post search instead of products.

```
//Add Search To Admin Bar
function boatparts_admin_bar_form() {
global $wp_admin_bar;
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
    'id' => 'boatparts_admin_bar_form',
    'parent' => 'top-secondary',
    'title' => '<form method="get" action="'.get_site_url().'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product">
<input name="s" type="text" style="height:20px;margin:5px 0;line-height:1em;"/> 
<input type="submit" style="height:18px;vertical-align:top;margin:5px 0;padding:0 2px;" value="Search Products"/> 
</form>'
));
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'boatparts_admin_bar_form');
```

Have it in my child theme's function.php. Driving me nuts trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hi Lucky Hunter, Thank You for replying. Worked perfectly as I would of hoped. I see now what I was missing. This was huge. Again Thank You!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **add hidden field** with **post-type** parameter:

```
<input name="post_type" value="product" type="hidden">
```

Also, I add some code for displaying search query in form after form submit and a small fix to the button styles.

**Fixed code snippet below:**

```
//Add Search To Admin Bar
function boatparts_admin_bar_form() {
  global $wp_admin_bar;

  $search_query = '';
  if ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'product' ) {
    $search_query = $_GET['s'];
  }

  $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
    'id' => 'boatparts_admin_bar_form',
    'parent' => 'top-secondary',
    'title' => '<form method="get" action="'.get_site_url().'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product">
      <input name="s" type="text" value="' . $search_query . '" style="height:20px;margin:5px 0;line-height:1em;"/> 
      <input type="submit" style="padding:3px 7px;line-height:1" value="Search Products"/> 
      <input name="post_type" value="product" type="hidden">
    </form>'
  ));
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'boatparts_admin_bar_form');
```

Search results sample:

[image: Search results sample]